# Mudar banner a cada refresh da página

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Tenho uma lista com 3 **Banners**.

Preciso mostrar sempre um diferente a cada **Refresh** da **Página**, mesmo após fechar o navegador.

Estou pensando em fazer um contador de impressões, cada vez que um **Banner** e mostrado acrescenta + 1 ao contador e faço essa verificação sempre que for mostrar.

Mas se tiver 2 **Banners** cadastrados e depois de várias impressões um terceiro for cadastrado iria quebrar esse esquema, pois somente o último a ser cadastrado iria ser mostrado.

Alguém sugere uma outra forma?

Comment: Na hora de você cadastrar/atualizar o outro banner você poderia, então, dar um update na tabela inteira e zerar o contador, já pensou nisso ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estou supondo que seu Banner esteja em uma lista de Banners, algo como `List<Banner>`:

```cs
banners.ElementAt(new Random().Next(0, banners.Count));
```

Comment: Com esse código sempre o primeiro **Banner** seria mostrado quando um novo acesso fosse feito certo?

Comment: Não. Neste caso ele sempre pega um Banner aleatório.

Comment: @cigano-morrison-mendez como eu faria isso com js ou jquery?

Comment: @ThiagoDiniz Escrevendo a estrutura usando Razor e usando um plugin JS pra rotacionar a lista. Faça uma pergunta que respondo pra você.

Comment: @cigano-morrison-mendez http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/80406/script-trocar-imagem-a-cada-reload