# Script trocar imagem a cada reload

Tags: javascript, jquery

Eu tenho 5 banners na home, e gostaria que a cada carregamento da home exibisse um dos banners. 
Ex: acessei o site e **exibe o banner 1**, naveguei em alguma página e voltei pra home **exibe o banner 2** creio que o mesmo funcionaria a cada vez que eu atualizasse a página.

Comment: @cigano-morrison-mendez pode me dar uma luz?

Answer (score 5):

Pode fazer usando cookie, algo parecido com isso:

```
$(function() {
    var bannerAtual = readCookie(bannerAtual);

    switch(bannerAtual) {
    case 1:
        //logica para colocar o banner 1        
        break;
    case 2:
         //logica para colocar o banner 2

        break;
    case 3:
         //logica para colocar o banner 3
        break;
    case 4:
         //logica para colocar o banner 4
        break;
    case 5:
         //logica para colocar o banner 5
        break;      
    default:    
    }

    if(bannerAtual == 5){
        createCookie('bannerAtual',1)
    }else{
        createCookie('bannerAtual',bannerAtual++)
    }

});

function createCookie(name,value,days) {
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
        var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
    }
    else var expires = "";
    document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
}

function readCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Podes usar o [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) para guardar e saber se já houve visitas. Se precisares de algo mais fiável sugiro fazeres isso com SESSIONs no lado do servidor.

Em JavaScript seria algo como:

```
var visitas = parseInt(localStorage.numeroVisitas, 10) || 0;
localStorage.numeroVisitas = visitas == 2 ? 0 : visitas + 1 ;

var banners = document.querySelectorAll('.banner');
[].forEach.call(banners, function (bn, i) {
    bn.classList[i == visitas ? 'add' : 'remove']('mostrar');
});
```

**jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8ufo6xk4/**

Comment: Cara ficou travado no acesso 2, era isso mesmo?

Comment: @ThiagoDiniz no meu exemplo a lógica é com duas imagens. Se precisas mais podes brrincar com o script e adaptar. Diz se precisares de ajuda.

Comment: preciso de ajuda sim :'( eu sei me virar com jquery js por mais vergonhoso não

Nesse caso eu usaria o LS pra guardar o qual foi visto e exibir o próximo e quando chegasse no 3º voltasse ao primeiro.

Comment: @ThiagoDiniz seria assim que procuras? -> http://jsfiddle.net/8ufo6xk4/

Comment: isso cara, matou a pau era isso mesmo, no caso eu teria uma estrutura de banners assim:

`<div class="box-banner">
        <a href="">
            <img src="img-1" alt="">
        </a>
    </div>

    <div class="box-banner">
        <a href="">
            <img src="img-2" alt="">
        </a>
    </div>

    <div class="box-banner">
        <a href="">
            <img src="img-3" alt="">
        </a>
    </div>`

Comment: @ThiagoDiniz ótimo. Juntei essa ideia à resposta.

Answer (score 1):

Caso esses banners estejam vindo via banco de dados, no *MySQL* por exemplo existe a função `ORDER BY RAND()`, onde pra cada requisição ele iria trazer um item aleatório.

Se você está apenas vendo imagens de uma pasta, você poderia listar as imagens em um `array` no *Javascript*, e criar uma variável que gere um valor randômico de acordo com a quantidade de imagens, e esse valor iria puxar o item específico, por exemplo:

```
var imagens = ["Imagem 1", "Imagem 2", "Imagem 3"]
var j = Math.floor((Math.random() * items.length) + 1);
```

Ai você chamaria a imagem da seguinte forma:

```
imagens[j - 1]
```

Coloquei -1 por que o J iria gerar valores entre 1 e a quantidade de itens,porém as chaves do `array` são de 0 a quantidade de `itens-1`.

Dessa forma, sempre que a página for recarregada o script será re-executado, com isso, irá sempre exibir uma imagem diferente (ou não, é aleatório, então é possível repetir duas ou mais vezes a mesma imagem).